# Incremental migration from Vue 1.x to Vue 2. Could I do it?

Tags: migration, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

My team and I have a medium-large web application which uses **Vue 1** and **Vue-router 0.7**.

Last days I was thinking about how I can migrate my project from Vue 1.x to **Vue 2**. In my opinion there are two possible methods:

1. Stop my web application development and migrate all the platform in
   a few weeks.
2. Do an incremental migration. Some componentes will use Vue 1 and
   other components will use Vue 2.

> CONSTRAINTS of each option

1. I can't stop my web aplication because It is stable in a production
   environment and I have to add features and fix issues.
2. I did satisfactory tests with components using Vue 1 and Vue 2. The
   problem is that It is not possible to use same Vue-router version,
   so I can't share routes and navigate between components...

The best option for my web application could be doing an **incremental migration** but...could It be possible?

Thank you for everything!

Answer (score 2):

I think it is possible.

The key thing is we have to make sure Vue 2.x and Vue 1.x are able to pass data to each other, and the reactivity should work to avoid complicated blocks of code.

I've made an example here: https://trandinhkhang.github.io

About Vue router, I think we can watch for a property and then do a router.push("some-url") in both Vue Router Vue 1 and Vue Router Vue 2 to navigate. Etc.

My company have the same troubles as yours and migrating a monolith into new platform is hard and seems impossible. Lolz. Incremental migration still the best option here.

Comment: Just edit my answer about vue router. Based on the possibility of passing data between Vue 1.x and Vue 2.x, I think we could solve the rest problems with the minimum of complex lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

VueJS 1.x and 2.x is totally different. 2.0 is written from scratch. VueJS have an awesome [migration helper](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-migration-helper) which can be used and it will do lots of work for you.

Read the following migrating guide: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html

I am not sure who gig your app is but it should not take more than 2 days for a medium size application.

Here are few points from their official doc:

**Where should I start in a migration?**

- Start by running the migration helper on a current project. We’ve carefully minified and compressed a senior Vue dev into a simple command line interface. Whenever they recognize an obsolete feature, they’ll let you know, offer suggestions, and provide links to more info.
- After that, browse through the table of contents for this page in the sidebar. If you see a topic you may be affected by, but the migration helper didn’t catch, check it out.
- If you have any tests, run them and see what still fails. If you don’t have tests, just open the app in your browser and keep an eye out for warnings or errors as you navigate around.
- By now, your app should be fully migrated. If you’re still hungry for more though, you can read the rest of this page - or just dive into the new and improved guide from the beginning. Many parts will be skimmable, since you’re already familiar with the core concepts.

By the way, You should not upgrade the app incrementally, In my experience, it will be total mess.